# Help me to find a better approach-Design Pattern

Tags: wcf, design-patterns

I am working on an ASP.Net web application in which several WCF services are being used. At client level, I am creating channel factory mechanism to invoke service operations. Right now, I have created an assembly having classes used for channel factory creation code for every service. As per my assumption this is some sort of
facade pattern. Please help me to find a better approach or any design pattern, which I can use here.

Comment: What is the purpose of the channel factory?  Why aren't you just using the clients generated in the proxies? Guess I'm trying to figure out what you are trying to accomplish.   Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you want to change? Is there any issue with the current approach? You can think of abstract factory also.

Comment: thanks for your reply.but i think abstract factory is more approppriate in creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes.